# Как преобразовать выражение в виде дерева обратной польской записью и вычислить это выражение в такой записе?

Tags: python

Вот выражение:

```
3 + 4 * 2 / (1-5) ** 2
```

А вот вид конечной обратной польской записи:

```
3 4 2 * 1 5 - 2 ^ / +
```

Надо чтобы были видны этапы перехода из обычной записи в польский. Можно применять любые библиотеки. 
https://studopedia.ru/20_7175_postfiksna-forma-zapisu-operatsiy-zvorotniy-polskiy-zapis.html
Здесь описано как это сделать, но не в python, а на бумаге.

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm#Python)